# É possível fazer a query "INSERT INTO tabela SET campo = 'valor' " no PostgreSQL?

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, query

É possível executar a query `INSERT INTO nome_tabela SET nome_campo = 'aaaa'` no banco PostgreSQL.

Precisei migrar uma loja virtual feita em *PHP* com banco *MySQL*, para *PostgreSQL*.

A parte da migração do banco eu consegui com auxilio de um programa e deu certo.

Felizmente o antigo programador usou PDO para programar, o que já me ajudou e muito, porém muitas *queries* de `INSERT` estão escritas da maneira que eu descrevi aqui.

Estou usando a versão 10.

Comment: Já testou pra ver se funciona?

Comment: Segundo a [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-insert.html), você pode usar o `set` caso venha utilizar o `DO UPDATE`. Nesse seu caso, eu recomendaria dá uma estudada em ORM também.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Não é possível.

Esse é um dos problemas de se fazer algo fora do padrão.

Na verdade isso é uma grande demonstração de que migrar banco de dados usado por uma aplicação não é algo trivial e não funciona de forma automática.

Infelizmente os maiores problemas não são tão visíveis e causam enormes problemas sem que sejam percebidos logo e as pessoas tendem a achar que é outra coisa, inclusive culpando o DB e sempre alguém argumentará que não deveria ter migrado porque se mostrou pior do que foi "vendido".

Infelizmente foi usado PDO. A única vantagem real dele é uma ilusão. Migrar de banco de dados envolve uma reavaliação total da semântica do acesso aos dados. O PDO só ajuda um pouco na sintaxe que é a parte fácil. Portanto o PDO ajuda menos que 10%, provavelmente bem menos, na migração. Mas o mais trágico é que dá a ilusão que ajudou perto ou 100%, o que não é verdade.

Se causar poucos problemas é porque já estava ruim antes.

Um ORM pode ter o mesmo ou pior efeito. ORM é útil em alguns cenários, mas a troca do banco de dados é uma ilusão. Na verdade ele é pior porque ele tende a deixar o acesso ruim sempre, uma camada como o PDO, se feito certo, pode ficar bom e só ficaria ruim em caso de migração.

Aqui sempre vemos perguntas falando dessas coisas e a pessoa acha que "apertará um botão" e tudo se resolverá. Problemas de arquitetura são os mais difíceis de resolver e infelizmente poucas pessoas sabem fazer arquitetura, a maioria acredita em coisas que não tem base na engenharia, só marketing.

Então quando a pessoa usa o PDO e usa sintaxe que não pode ser migrada, a pessoa não sabia o que estava fazendo. Se a pessoa fez errado na sintaxe, que é a parte fácil, imagine na semântica.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta @Maniero.
Eu concordo com muitas coisas que você mencionou.
Como ainda estou em processo de aprendizado, vou procurar focar meus estudos nessas questões que você abordou. Eu realmente tentei executar essa query e o PostgreSQL não trabalha dessa maneira. Eu agradeço pela ajuda de todos. Problema resolvido com a sintaxe "INSERT INTO tabela(campo) VALUES('valor')"

Comment: +1, em especial pela "lenda do PDO". Eis mais uma prova de que essa conversa é mais "marketing" do que qualquer coisa. @Gabriel provavelmente a solução no seu caso é um simples search-replace nos SQL para adequar a sintaxe, praticamente todos os editores de código fazem isso de uma forma ou outro.